# Xamarin Form Debugging - iOS Simulator Device list disappeared

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am debugging Xamarin.iOS on Windows, and I have paired to Mac succesfully. The debugging device list disappeared today when I tried to debug on iPhone 12, please see attached photo:

[No iOS Device to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YJPy.png)

Before today, I was able to see full list. I've done my search but didn't get luck, can someone please help me? TIA

Comment: have you restarted VS and/or rebooted both machines?

Comment: Are you saying that you previously debugged to simulators, then debugged on an actual iPhone 12 device, then simulators do not show? If so, unplug the phone, and reboot mac, then reboot pc. Also, I see the "Simulator" dropdown arrow: when you click that, no simulators appear?  [Worst case, if nothing else works, if you can get the simulator to launch again from the mac, the next time pc reboots, VS Win should see it. I do this by downloading source to Mac, using VS Mac to build and launch to simulator.]

Comment: Another possibility: do you have mac set to do automatic updates? If so, did Xcode update to v. 14?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I found out the issue was caused by the latest Xcode (version 14), Visual Studio 2022 doesn't support Xcode 14 yet (at least iPhone simulators). Downgrading the version to 13.4.1 fixed it. Thank you for trying to help me!

Comment: You can check my answer if you are curious

Comment: Yep. That's why I asked if your Xcode had updated to v.14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Downgrading Xcode** to 13.4.1 fixed the issue.

Hat tip to ToolmakerSteve

After hours of researching, I found out what caused the issue.

Xcode updated itself to Xcode 14, and Visual Studio 2022 for Windows doesn't support Xcode 14 yet (at least iPhone simulators).

Here's a similar issue I found: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15946

Here's the **solution**: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15954

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed by Microsoft with latest release of Xamarin.iOS `16.0.0.72` and XCode `14.0.1 (21336)`. After updating, now the simulators with version 16.0 is listing down properly.